# Spring MVC Daylight saving issue

Tags: java, spring, timezone, dst

I've working on Spring MVC for quite some time and bumped into this problem

I set the application timezone to New_York with the following code:

```
public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
            System.out.println("Eastern time zone");
        }
    }
}
```

Next, i'm submitting a form and reading it with the code:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveschedule")
@ResponseBody
public String saveSchedule(
@ModelAttribute CommonSchedule schedule, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>          " + schedule.getSendingTime());
    System.out.println(new Date());
}
```

If I select the time, 15:30:00, i'm getting the output
I'm getting following output:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>          Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 EST 1970
Mon Aug 26 06:20:01 EDT 2013
```

I want to know, how come spring mvc form submission getting EST whereas my application is EDT

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know, how come spring mvc form submission getting EST whereas my application is EDT

You're using the `America/New_York` time zone, which alternates between EST and EDT as daylight saving time changes occur.

When you use a time without a date, you're implying the date of `1/1/1970` - which for `America/New_York` was in EST at that time.

You should instead be applying the time to a particular date so it will use the correct offset for that time.